# How to show Informix sysprocedures.paramtypes column via JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, informix

I have problem with executing SQL query via native JDBC driver. This query is used by my program that make raport of Informix database schema: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576621-dump-informix-schema-to-text/

```
SELECT procname, numargs, isproc, paramtypes, variant, handlesnulls, parallelizable
FROM sysprocedures
WHERE internal='f' AND mode IN ('D', 'd', 'O', 'o')
ORDER BY procname, numargs, procid
```

It works when I use ODBC, but this program can be run by Jython and JDBC, and in JDBC I got exception:

```
Dla tego typu danych jest wymagana dostosowana mapa typów. [SQLCode: -79769], [SQLState: IX000]
```

English translation (I hate JDBC error descriptions in native languages, they only make troubles when you search solutions in network):

```
-79769 A customized type map is required for this data type
Explanation: You must register a customized type map to use any opaque types.
```

I also tried simply:

```
SELECT * FROM sysprocedures
```

But this also do not work in JDBC.

I see that `paramtypes` is a problem: query works if I remove it.

What must I register to map this column into something that JDBC can show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paramtypes` column is a complex column type, created using some of the extensibility features of Informix.  I suspect that the ODBC driver works around it by doing the equivalent of:

```
SELECT procname, numargs, isproc, paramtypes::LVARCHAR, variant, handlesnulls, parallelizable
  FROM sysprocedures
 WHERE internal = 'f' AND mode IN ('D', 'd', 'O', 'o')
 ORDER BY procname, numargs, procid
```

That is, it forces a conversion to a string.  When I run the query (in my SQLCMD), I get output, but a lot of the procnames are empty strings.  I'm not quite sure what's going on there.

Comment: Casting to `LVARCHAR` works! I tried `VARCHAR` but without success. Now it returns strings like "integer,integer,varchar". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than working with that denormalised version of the parameter types, why not join

```sql
SELECT p.*, c.*, informix.schema_coltypename(c.paramtype, c.paramxid)
FROM sysprocedures p
JOIN sysproccolumns c ON p.procid = c.procid
WHERE p.internal='f' AND p.mode IN ('D', 'd', 'O', 'o')
ORDER BY p.procname, p.numargs, p.procid, c.paramid
```